# I wish to assign contacts, accounts to a particular business unit and time frame will be defined Is it possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, sharing, record

In Salesforce, i wish to assign contacts, accounts to a particular business unit and time frame will be defined. All the users in the particular business unit will see those records in that time frame. After that no. Is there any way we can achieve this..

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "all users ... will see..."? can you explain the process the users follows to "see" the particular contacts/accounts? Is it a list view on the contact  or account homepage, is it via a report?

Comment: How many business units are there? If there will only ever be 5, for example, this would look different that hundreds. Also, how will the records be assigned? Manually? How will the time frame be defined?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing ("visibility") is based on ownership, so the ownership would need to change. You could create Queues (for most objects), and assign users ("business unit") to that queue. They would be able to see all records in this queue. You can then set up a time-based workflow rule that fires when a custom date/time field ("timeframe") is filled out; when the timer expires, it can call a field update to change the owner from the queue to another user, which will remove visibility for that record from the business unit, unless they have visibility from some other source (e.g. sharing, role hierarchy, ec). Note that queues allow records to be transferred from them (using "accept"), so you might need a validation rule or other code to prevent the transfer from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing is controlled through sharing setting (RecordShare, sharing rules, etc). One could create a Visualforce page or some other interface to have some Apex Code automatically create a share for the appropriate business unit. This model would require a scheduled Apex Code class to run periodically, query for records that should no longer be shared because the timeframe elapsed, and then delete the manual shares. One could also create a time-based workflow rule to kick off a field update that would call a trigger that would delete the shares as well; this would give a higher resolution as to the shutoff time, since it is inconvenient to have to run a scheduled class very frequently. In any event, this method works without the need to change ownership.